# php form not posting to self

Tags: php, html

I have a simple dropdown menu which posts the result to itself but when i choose one of the options in the drop down menu it does not echo back the result as expected.

I'm sure i've just missed out something simple but can't spot it. Any ideas? The form posts but does not echo back $user_settings.

```
<?php
include "functions.php";
connect();

$sql="SELECT user_id, user_realname FROM users ORDER BY user_realname ASC";
    $result=mysql_query($sql);

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        $name=$row['user_realname'];
        $options.="<OPTION VALUE=>".$name.'</option>';
        }

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $user_realname = $_POST['username_select'];
    $user_select = mysql_query("SELECT user_id, user_realname FROM users WHERE user_realname = '$user_realname'")
    or die ("Could not get user data");

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($user_select)){

        $user_settings = $row['user_id'];
        echo $user_settings;
    }
}
?>

<html>
    <head>
        <body>
            <form action="<?php echo $PHP_SELF;?>" method="POST">
                <tr><label>Choose User to Edit</tr>
                <tr><SELECT NAME="username_select"><OPTION VALUE=""></option>User's Name<?php echo $options;?></SELECT></label></tr>
                <tr><input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit"></tr>
            </form>
            <?php echo $user_settings;?>
            <br/>
            <a href="admin.php">Go Back</a>
        </body>
    </head>
</html>
```

Comment: Never construct SQL queries like this. You're leaving yourself open to SQL injection.

Comment: This is just for an internal office project at the moment so not too worried about SQL injections although i will probably added the real escapes when i've finished.

Comment: That's an incredibly bad way to program. You also shouldn't use the `mysql_` functions at all; they're all deprecated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

User `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` instead of $PHP_SELF

Comment: Or simply leave action blank.

Comment: I've left it blank and tried using $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] but $user_settings is never echo'd back

Comment: try adding `var_dump($_POST);` inside of `if(isset($_POST['submit'])){ ... }`  and see if it prints out info.. if it does you have no entrys in db..

Comment: thanks Pēteris, this helped me work out the issue. It was not posting what i thought it was. all good now thanks.